# Prove that two Partial fraction Integration answers are the same

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I did the actual Partial Fraction Integration for: $\int \frac{x^2+8}{x^3+8} dx$ and got: $\ln(x+2)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{3}})$.

I need to prove that my answer above is equal to: $\ln(x+2)+\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{3} \arctan[\frac{1}{6}(2x-2)\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: Please try to use MathJax for formatting your questions, it makes it much easier to read. See a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $$\sqrt{3}/6=1/(2\sqrt{3})$$

Comment: And also $1/\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3}/3$ via rationalizing the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}} = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{3}$. With that and the fact that $\frac{1}{6}(2x-2) = \frac{x-1}{3}$ the two results are basically already the same, just a little bit of variation in the fractions happened.